# SSIS - using conditional split without losing row-order

Tags: ssis

I'm processing a flat file in SSIS with the following possible record structure:

```
ACTION_TYPE   PERSON_ID     TIME_STAMP
-----------   ---------     ---------------
  1 / 2       (9 digits)    (up to millis)
```

Logic states that i have to perform operation 1 for each person before i perform operation 2.
Also, "actions" can appear in file without any limitations: couples of 1's and 2's, only 1, only 2, etc. for each person.

Now, the flow is:

```
                                                      __(1)___> PERFORM 1 ON PERSON (DB)
SOURCE --> SORT BY OPERATION --> CONDITIONAL-SPLIT --|
                                                     |__(2)___> PERFORM 2 ON PERSON (DB)
```

Everything worked OK, until i noticed that the order of records coming out of the conditional-split is not preserved - i.e., when a "duo of rows" of 1 and 2 for the same person enters the split, it might be performed TOGETHER, in parallel - leading to a race condition or even constraint-violation in my DB (because the table is built upon the assumption that 1's are always performed before 2).

Sorting the data using the timestamp can be very helpful, but the split would mess the order again, just like with the sorting i've done here.

Any ideas how to "sequentiallize" the otuput of the con-split? can i perform a flow if a fully-sequential mode somehow?

Thanks,
Harel

Comment: You can separate the task into two data flow tasks.

Comment: Hey, thought of this option - but it's not good, because as i mentioned above - every type-1 action must be perform after type-2 action for the same person - so i can' just perform all type-1 actions in a separate dataflow, and leave the type-2 actions to another dataflow...

Comment: Well, if you need to use with data from the first split you might want to think about caching the result, but without knowing what exactly you'd like to perform it's a wild guess. You can also think of some temporary table, so you drop people after 1st action performed there and continue onwards from then.